# Prove that $AS$ is perpendicular to $IT$

Tags: geometry

Let $(O),(I)$ be the circumcircle and incircle of triangle $ABC$, resp. $IA, IB, IC$ intersect $(O)$ again in $D, E, F$, resp. $AE, AF$ intersect $BC$ in $M, N$, resp. Let $L$ be the Lemoine point of triangle $ABC$. $LB, LC$ intersect $CA, AB$ in $P, Q$, resp. $PQ$ intersects $AE, AF$ in $G, H$, resp. $MH$ intersects $NG$ in $S$. Perpendicular bisector of $ID$ intersects the line passing through $O$ and parallel to $BC$ in $T$. Prove that $AS \perp IT$.

Comment: Wellcome to MSE! This is a very complicated geometrical setting, please share with the community the own thoughts, the own effort to solve the problem. Usually, offering as much "content" as possible is the good way to ask a question. Providing a picture for the problem is for instance a first good choice to accompany the posted problem. Could you please add more information to the question to fit the general rules of posting on this this site?!

Comment: Some picture please!

Comment: Sorry but I dont know how to post the picture. Could you please solve without the picture?

Answer (score 1):

This could not be inserted as a comment, so it is an answer.

The picture for the many points is:

[image: Complicated geometry problem mathematics stackexchange lemoine point 3488104]

The point $M$ is somewhere in the far East.

---

As it can be extracted from the picture, this is not a short story to type as a solution, so **please insert content**. What have you tried?! What kind of solution is asked for? (Using trilinear/barycentric coordinates? Purely synthetic solution?) Which is **the source** of the problem? Which is the level expected for the solution? Which is your level?